# Building contextify under Windows 7 x64 (for NodeJS jQuery)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I try to get **node-jquery** working. **contextify** is one of the dependencies (required for **jsdom**).

**contextify** needs to be built somehow using Python. But this does not seem to work on Windows 7 x64. At least one my computer :)

After some readings ([#10](https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/issues/10), [#12](https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/issues/12), [#17](https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/pull/17)) and trying some binaries provided by this [fork](https://github.com/Benvie/contextify) and this [one](https://github.com/springmeyer/contextify) I can get it work ...

I've got the same error from `node-gyp configure` or from `node-gyp rebuild` (`npm install jquery`) :

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
info downloading: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.14/node-v0.6.14.tar.gz
info downloading: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.14/x64/node.lib
info downloading: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.14/node.lib
spawn python [ 'D:\\Users\\ngryman\\.node-gyp\\0.6.14\\tools\\gyp_addon',
  'binding.gyp',
  '-ID:\\Users\\ngryman\\build\\config.gypi',
  '-f',
  'msvs',
  '-G',
  'msvs_version=2010' ]
  File "D:\Users\ngryman\.node-gyp\0.6.14\tools\gyp_addon", line 40
    print 'Error running GYP'
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
ERR! Error: `gyp_addon` failed with exit code: 1
  at ChildProcess.onCpExit (D:\Users\ngryman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
node-gyp\lib\configure.js:226:16)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:70:17)
  at maybeExit (child_process.js:360:16)
  at Process.onexit (child_process.js:396:5)
ERR! not ok
```

It seems there is a syntax error ... I am not very comfortable with Python.

Here are my versions :

- Python: 3.2.3
- NodeJS: 0.6.14

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use x64 version (I guess)? 32 bit version work well for me on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: x64 is just the version of my OS.

Comment: Because I see http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.14/x64/node.lib. Do you use 64bit version of Node.js. I use Node 32bit on Win7 x64 and contextify works fine

Comment: You can try: update to node 0.6.15, switch to Python 2.7 :-? It could be not compatible with Python 3 and did you have Visual C++ installed?

Comment: Ok ! Updated to node 0.6.15 (32 bits), Python 2.7 (32 bits) it works like charm :) Thanks !

Comment: I have Visual Studio Express installed, I don't know if it makes the difference. I bet for a 32bits / 64bits conflict, or something like that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I managed to build it, but I can say it was really painful. In fact it was so painful that it caused temporary amnesia and I forgot how I did it.

You need Visual Studio as well, apart from python.

Anyway, I have the binaries, I just uploaded them to gihub:
https://github.com/mihaifm/jsdom_binaries

Just clone that repo, copy what's inside `node_modules` to your project, and you're good to go!

**Update (march 2013)**

These binaries are no longer needed (at least not for Win7, with VS2010 installed). `jsdom` and `contextify` can now be installed just with `npm`:

```
npm install jsdom
npm install contextify
```

(you still need python and a MS C++ compiler, as mentioned in the requirements for [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp))

I updated the repo as well, just in case anyone still has trouble installing.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Even if I still don't know how to build it, this solve my problem.

Comment: Binaries are a huge help (thankyou!), but devs should note they were last updated April 2012.

Comment: @Simon you're right, however these are no longer needed. `jsdom` and `contextify` now install ok just with `npm install`

Comment: @mihai are you sure?? It definitely didn't install for me yesterday. Don't you still need Python and MS C++ compiler?  (Unless I had a different issue?)

Comment: @Simon you still need python and a MS C++ compiler. The requirements are listed in the readme for [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp), which is the tool used by npm to build native modules.

Comment: @mihai Oh dear, so it's *still really painful*, and binaries might still be helpful.  I don't want to have to download and install 600mb+ Visual Studio Express just to install a simple node module.

Comment: on an x64 Win7 computer with VS 2010 Express it only worked when I added *--arch=ia32*, e.g. `npm install jsdom --arch=ia32`. Without, it failed with "InvalidPlatform...error MSB8007". Hat tip to https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-expat/issues/59

Comment: OMG +1,000... clicking "Show more comments" saved my life, thanks @mattwilkie

Comment: < Update (march 2013)                                                    ^ I still can't install it

Comment: Thank you kindly Mihai! Just lost 2h with this.

Comment: @mihai I'm unable to install contextify

Answer (score 3):

I was able to successfully build node-jquery on Windows 7(x64) with node 0.8.11(x64), and Python 2.7.3.
Here's what my jquery structure looks like:

```
┬ jquery@1.7.3
├── htmlparser@1.7.6
├─┬ jsdom@0.2.19
│ ├─┬ contextify@0.1.3
│ │ └── bindings@1.0.0
│ ├── cssom@0.2.5
│ ├── cssstyle@0.2.3
│ └─┬ request@2.11.4
│   ├─┬ form-data@0.0.4
│   │ ├── async@0.1.22
│   │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.3
│   │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│   └── mime@1.2.7
├── location@0.0.1
├── navigator@1.0.1
└── xmlhttprequest@1.4.2
```

according to the author of node-gyp
https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/155

> Ya, Python 3 and Python 2 are not compatible, however gyp requires
>   Python 2.

Comment: Right! I've discovered that after. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the full feature-set of Contextify, **Cheerio** is *much faster* and much easier to install on Windows, and provides most of the jQuery functions you would use server-side.

http://matthewmueller.github.com/cheerio/

Answer (score 2):

I built it using

- Windows 8 x64 DP
- Python 2.7 (on PATH)
- Node 0.8.11 x86 (on PATH)
- Visual Studio 2010 (requires installed 'Visual C++' feature)

contextify 0.1.3 binaries (probably only working with the 32-bit Node version) can be found at [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/AndiDog/contextify-binaries). They work together with jsdom 0.2.18 (current version as of 2012-10-13).

Comment: +1 for publishing the binaries (yay!), although they are fairly out of date now.

Answer (score 1):

From the jsdom readme.md:

#### Windows

- A recent copy of the *x86* version of [Node.js for Windows], *not* the x64 version.
- A copy of [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express).
- A copy of [Python 2.7], installed in the default location of `C:\Python27`.

I did exactly this and it worked fine, except that for me the x64 version worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to install the `windows-build-tools` package. That has everything you need to build contextify. Run the command from an power shell prompt running with administrator rights.

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools

> These tools are required to compile popular native modules. It will also install **Python 2.7**, configuring your machine and npm appropriately.
>
> **Contents**
>
> - Visual C++ Compilers (targeting x86, X64 and ARM)
> - Visual C++ Compilers (targeting x86, X64 and ARM)
> - Visual C++ headers & libraries (CRT & STL)
> - Visual C++ build scripts (targeting Windows desktop)
> - Microsoft Build Tools 2015 (MSBuild)
> - Windows SDK 8.1 (optional, on by default)
> - Windows SDK 10 (optional, off by default)
> - ATL and MFC (optional, off by default)
> - C++ Build tools specific command prompts

Comment: This should really be accepted answer, very simple and elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure I was using Python 2.7.3 and running the cmd line as administrator (right click run as administrator).

`> python --version`

I built it using

- Windows 7 x64
- Python 2.7.3
- Node 0.8.17
- Visual Studio 10