# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'run'

Tags: node.js, jsdom

In the **Done** function the err object has a single error which is **"TypeError: Object # has no method 'run' in file 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js' ".**

```
 var jsdom = require('jsdom-nogyp');

jsdom.env({
    html: '<html><body></body></html>',
    scripts: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'],
    done: function (err, window) {
        if (err)
            throw (err);
        var $ = window.jQuery;

        $('body').append("<div class='testing'>Hello World</div>");
        console.log($(".testing").text()); // outputs Hello World
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`jsdom-nogyp` has taken out `contextify` from the dependencies, which is what `jsdom` uses to run scripts. So use the real `jsdom` instead:

```
npm install jsdom
```

And:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am hoping to host on Windows as the other areas of my stack are better served in such an OS.  Is there any way of getting JSDOM with contextify to stand up on node running on Windows?

Comment: I don't do development on Windows. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226301/building-contextify-under-windows-7-x64-for-nodejs-jquery) may help, and there are probably other question on SO that could help.